# Bluetooth in SWIFT: Get 19 bytes data and convert to UInt

Tags: swift, bluetooth, byte, nsdata

I would like to connect the Concept2 rower to my iPhone.
The corresponding Bluetooth data sheet can be found here : http://www.concept2.com/files/pdf/us/monitors/PM5_BluetoothSmartInterfaceDefinition.pdf

I would like to get back the different data: ElapsedTime, Distance, Split/interval, etc..

From the UUID adress 0X0031 I get a 19 bytes data in the following order:Elapsed Time Lo (0.01 sec lsb), Elapsed Time Mid, Elapsed Time High, Distance Lo (0.1 m lsb), Distance Mid, Distance Hi, ...

So 1 byte corresponds to 1 attribute.

I need to extract the bytes corresponding to the attribute and convert them.
I think all bytes data are unsigned types (for extraction).

The ElapsedTime variable is on 3 bytes. SO to build the ElapsedTime variable I was computing like this:

```
class func dataToUnsignedBytes8(value:NSData) -> [UInt8]{
    let count = value.length
    var array = [UInt8](count: count, repeatedValue: 0)
    value.getBytes(&array, length: count * sizeof(UInt8))
    return array
}

class func getElapsedTime(value : NSData) -> Double {
    let dataFromSensor = dataToSignedBytes8(value)
    let elapsedTime = Double(dataFromSensor[2] * 65536 + dataFromSensor[1]*256 + dataFromSensor[0])
    return elapsedTime
}
```

But I'm not sure about what I'm doing.

Does the ElapsedTime_Hi byte is at index 3 of dataFromSensor, ElapsedTime_Mid is at index 2 of dataFromSensor and ElapsedTime_Lo at index 0 dataFromSensor ?

What is the best way to extract the corresponding byte for other attributes ?

Thank you in advance

Regards

Comment: `255` should be `256` , and the array indices probably should be 2,1,0 instead of 3,2,0. – But why don't you test it yourself? Fill a 19 byte array with sample data and check if the value extraction works correctly.

Comment: OK for the 256 instead of 255.
OK for the indices I don't know why I write it like this...

I don't now what's look like the 19bytes and I don't have a rower at disposal for now. It's the first time I try to use BLE device

Comment: I edit the code with Martin R's remarks. But how to be sure the first byte received will be at index 0 ?

Comment: There is a problem conversion type from this code:
When I calculate let elapsedTime = Double(dataFromSensor[2] * 65536 + dataFromSensor[1]*256 + dataFromSensor[0])
-> I have an error message : "Integer literral overflows when stored into UInt8

I don't know why ? If I change UInt8 to UInt32 I don't have the error message but I'm not sure that the byte which I'm interessting are still at index 0,1, 2

Thank your for your help